# Comparing DateTimes in ruby, can you answer this puzzle?

Tags: ruby

How is this possible?

[image]

Comparing two DateTime classes with apparently similar values, and I get a surprising answer.

Indexer friendly information:

```
[9] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at
=> Sat, 20 Jul 2019 19:28:40 +0000
[10] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> value
=> Sat, 20 Jul 2019 19:28:40 +0000
[11] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at.class
=> DateTime
[12] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> value.class
=> DateTime
[13] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> value.to_i
=> 1563650920
[14] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at.to_i
=> 1563650920
[15] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at == value
=> false
[16] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at.to_date == value.to_date
=> true
[17] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)>
```

Some more info:

```
[17] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at.to_time
=> 2019-07-20 19:28:40 +0000
[18] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> value.to_time
=> 2019-07-20 19:28:40 +0000
[19] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at.to_time == value.to_time
=> false
```

Seems that the time part is culpable. But how?

From time docs https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html

```
All times may have fraction. Be aware of this fact when comparing times with each other – times that are apparently equal when displayed may be different when compared.
```

So where is this fraction and how does is get screwed up?

Comment: What is the class of each object?

Comment: @anothermh DateTime

Comment: @Carcigenicate what other relevant information?

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok, added some more intresting stuff also.

Comment: What about the microseconds? What do `scheduled_shift.start_at.usec` and `value .usec` return?

Comment: @spickermann indeed the microseconds where the issue, I guess this are the factional part.

Comment: Please don't use images to show text. Instead, copy and paste the text into the question, formatting it appropriately. Images severely restrict what we can do with the information and force us to retype the text to reuse it.

Comment: @vol7ron, it was probably downvoted because it doesn't meet the guidelines. "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" describes it. As it is, the question can't be reproduced or confirmed because the code doesn't replicate the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan ahh, but mcve is a suggestion. Clearly here, where it isn’t known what is producing the problem it is less about code syntax and more about system/program design. Given the examples, I think he made an attempt to show what he knew and anything more would require comments by others asking specific questions of what else needs to be presented. The answers also suggest that he provided what was needed. Perhaps the downvoted were prior to his IRB statements?

Comment: Possibly. Discussions on [meta] are always interesting because they bring up such things. SO is global, and it's easy to forget that it takes at least 24 hrs. to get members around the world to read, comment, respond, re-read and often people don't repeal their votes once something is amended. MCRE is more than a suggestion, it's a measure of how much work was put in prior to asking, and if the elements given in the document aren't there then it's used to vote to close. SO is an archive of programming questions and solutions, like an encyclopedia so the info needed is important.

Comment: Can’t disagree with any of that

Answer (score 3):

Ruby compares the time with fraction of seconds (that's what they mean by "fraction"). For example,

```rb
t0, t1 = Time.now, Time.now
t0 == t1
# => false
```

Or

```rb
t0, t1 = DateTime.now, DateTime.now
t0 == t1
# => false
```

If you use `to_f` you will see the difference in the fraction of seconds.

Now, if you do this:

```rb
t0, t1 = Time.now, Time.now
t0 = Time.at(t0.to_i)
t1 = Time.at(t1.to_i)
t0 == t1
# => true
```

This will work because you are creating a new time stamp with no fraction of seconds.

Moreover, if you are interested in checking directly the fraction of seconds:

```rb
Time.now.strftime("%N")
```

Comment: `Time.now.subsec` for a real fraction

Comment: @steenslag true : )

Comment: `t0 == t1` is not always `true`: `require 'time'; 2_000_000.times.map { [Time.now, Time.now] }.reject { |t0, t1| Time.at(t0.to_i) == Time.at(t1.to_i) } #=> [[2019-07-20 19:29:15 -0700, 2019-07-20 19:29:16 -0700], [2019-07-20 19:29:16 -0700, 2019-07-20 19:29:17 -0700]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, well that can happen in really seldom cases, I believe. As you can see, if the definition of ```t0``` and ```t1``` are made at a time that it's very close to when the "seconds" is about to "turn" (example, 15 sec to 16 sec), ```t0```might be defined in the 15 sec portion and ```t1``` in the 16 sec portion. You will notice that they are not true always by a factor of 1 sec. You just detect the limit of our machines to process. Very interesting comment.

Answer (score 2):

So if you do `to_f` you get a surprising result

```
[21] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> value.to_f
=> 1563650920.0
[22] pry(#<Api::Requests::Schemas::PickupRequestContract>)> scheduled_shift.start_at.to_f
=> 1563650920.036918
```

To bad stack overflow bans swearing, it would have make for a nice outro for this saga.